# Keeping dValIds For auto-generated dimensions consistent

Tags: endeca

I am working with Endeca 6.4.1 and have many auto-generated dimensions present in my pipeline (*mapped using Dev-studio*), the application's indexing is CAS-less. So only FCM is creating Dimensions and assigning dValIds. I am using Endeca SEO, so the dVal Id directly reflects in my URL, and if an auto-gen dimension's value's Id changes, a link to that navigation State is lost.

I have a flat file as the dimension's source, for example

```
product.feature|neon finish
```

What I want is that, if the value some day changes to Neon-finish or Neon color, the dValId that was assigned to neon finish should be transferred to the new value. I can keep a custom mapping of the change to track that neon finish has been changed to a new value.

Is there any way to achieve this, may be by using some manipulators?

Please share your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

There are two basic ways to do this:

1) Update the state files when you change a dimension value (APPDIR/data/state/autogen_dimensions.xml ). This would most likely be a manual process.

2) A more robust but complex solution is to change the dimension values to be some ID number and use a synonym for the display name. Then the display name can change without a change to the id number. This may require some serious changes to your pipeline.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks, I am looking for making changes to achieve #2 above.  I am not able to understand how to do that to an auto-gen dimension. Do you think writing a manipulator in the pipeline would be a good idea?

Comment: You can do it with a manipulator but ultimately your data source needs to have some unchanging identifier for the dimension value so that when the change does take place the system will not even care.

Comment: I started to write a Java manipulator but then thought it would only modify my records, and not dimensions. Is there a way I could manipulate dimensions after being created from Dev studio,  I am unable to understand where should that customization be added in the pipeline, should be before Indexer Adapter?

Comment: You can programtically modify the dimensions.xml file before or after forge. Or you can modify the property values that are mapped to the dimension values. But I don't think that you can modify the dimensions themselves in pipeline.